# Diablo 3 Ultimate Evil Edition - PS4 difficulty versus PC

Tags: diablo-iii, pc, ps4

I am a long-time gamer of the PC version. Within the last month, I have acquired the PS4 version. After a great deal of time in the game, it is starting to feel like the PS4 version is naturally easier (across the board) than the PC version. A character leveled to Torment 4 capabilities would take months on the PC for me. Maybe not that much, but it takes a long time, a lot of good gear, and it's always hard.

On the PS4 version I was in Torment 4, and it's easy within a quarter of the time. Is the difficult different, or was I Just lucky with gear this play through?

Comment: One thing to note is that Console and PC do not get patched at the same level. So while things get changed regularly on battle.net I'm not sure what the same changes are made on the console. I know there are differences between the two, but don't know enough to give you a full answer.

Comment: I notice a few minor differences, but I know most of the patches are in sync? Like the newest patch is being released for all platforms, when it comes out.

Comment: They have in the past tried to make them line up, but have not always been the case. I know when they were hotfixing bounties in the past when they first came out, the changes were PC only until they did everything in a massive update on consoles.

Comment: I'd have to say that one of the main reasons the game *feels* different is probably because it *is* different. As stated in earlier comments, updates and content is managed differently between the two versions, however one of the main points would be that the console version would feel a lot more "arcade-y" because the entire environment is different. The controls are different, the input is different, even the fact that the community is different has an impact on the game.

Comment: I've never actually played the console versions, but from what I've seen from gameplay on youtube the controls are a lot less precise than they are on PC (which is understandable). Since the player has less precision over the control of what their character does (it seemed to me that the closest enemies were auto targeted) the easier the overall game has to be in order to compensate for optimized attack plans. I'm not sure how someone would focus fire anything on consoles.

Comment: @JekwA I play on PS4, and it's not that bad in single player. Not as clean as a mouse, but not bad. You get a giant health bar for the current target, and can "lock on" with a shoulder button. *Local multiplayer* is where it gets dicey. It's sometimes very hard to tell who is targeting who. Most of the time it's not a big deal, but I've often thrown a slow time bubble across the screen when trying for something near me (because somebody else had it targeted and I thought I did). With melee it's not much of an issue either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Version

PC should be faster due to superior inputs.

### Long Version

As far as I know, there is no major difficulty difference between console and PC. I found no mention of any distinct ones, at least.

#### Console *"Advantages"*

The *Ultimate Evil Edition* has a couple of things that **could** be considered advantageous:

- Dodging
- Nemesis System
- Lock-On Targeting

Dodging is really the one that sticks out here as being an advantage, but it's not really that huge, and it's probably outweighed by the superior inputs of mouse and keyboard.

The Nemesis system is only active if you have friends playing, and even then it may give you some loot every now and then. Again, not a major difference.

Lock-on targeting is just another response to the less responsive controls, and doesn't bring any real advantage I can think of.

#### PC Advantages

The PC version has a couple of advantages too:

- Superior Input Capabilities
- Aimable skills
- Faster Inventory Management
- Earlier patches (if this is still the case)

The first two really set the bar for why playing on PC gives you an edge. You have more control of where you're character is going, where your projectiles are flying and where your area of effect skills are placed. Things that come to mind is teleporting to specific spots without turning to face them, playing crowd control effects *between* you and your opponents, etc. All only limited by how fast you can aim with a mouse. This becomes even more important with the ever-increasing speeds of the most popular builds (Whirlwind Barb and Dash Monk come to mind).

The same goes for managing inventory etc. Even with a good controller system, I still give the edge to the PC here. This isn't difficulty per se, but since you mentioned the time it took to reach a certain level, it adds up.

Earlier patches is important due to the power creep (or exponential power increase as it seems these days) that comes with each subsequent patch. When caught up, this obviously doesn't make a difference.

#### Conclusion

All in all, I think it must have come down to luck or how comfortable you are with the control schemes, as I can't see any reason the console version would be easier (unless there are differences in drop rates or monster/player power, but I wasn't able to find any mention of such).

---

On a personal note, I think it only took me a few days to reach a point where I was speedfarming Torment 6 on hardcore this season (3) without having to pay too much attention. If it takes you months, then I suggest looking up some builds (for example, [here](http://www.diablofans.com/builds)).

Unless you prefer to find your own way, then I salute you and wish you the best of luck!

Comment: You didn't include the Nephlem Glory damage buff on console which can go either way depending on how you argue about it. According to other people's tests, the monster health on console is actually double what it is on PC, so 2x dmg from NG puts console players in ratio to PC players, but without it, console is clearly more difficult, since you have to keep the buff alive through kills, that should argue towards console being harder. http://us.battle.net/d3/en-us/forum/topic/16779638111#1